# python Popen shell=True behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Why would this doesn't work: `subprocess.Popen(["ls -l | grep myfile"], shell=False)`
But this line works: `subprocess.Popen(["ls -l | grep myfile"], shell=True)`
I understand this shell=True create a sub shell internally and execute command. But didn't understand how this affect Popen behavior

Comment: Try doing `subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l", "|", "grep", "shell"], shell=False)`

Comment: My intention is to understand Popen behavior rather than make it work. Looking for an explanation

Comment: It won't work as desired as it will assume '|', 'grep' and 'shell' filenames, @Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

Popen() does the subprocess management with the code inside the subprocess module. It doesn't know about piping with `|`, and it doesn't know whether the string you pass is a program or an argument, like in your example with `ls` it will assume that everything else except `ls` itself is arguments for the program. It will try to execute the first item in list and pass all other items as arguments.

When you use `shell=True`, you may think of it (e.g. on UNIX) as running `/bin/sh -c` with arglist you provided as a string. So

```
Popen('ls -l | grep myfile', shell=True)
```

is something close to

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'ls -l | grep myfile'])
```

In both cases, argument handling is actually done by your shell.

For piping and `shell=False`, you should use `subprocess.PIPE` and stdout/stdin/stderr redirections with the tools provided in subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

`shell=True` is used to pass a single *string* as a command line to a shell. While it's technically possible to pass a list, it's probably never what you want.

```
subprocess.Popen("ls -l | grep myfile", shell=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `shell=False`, you must be to use like it:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ls","-l"],shell=False)
```